# How to generate a Guid in Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, guid

How can I generate a Guid in Netbeans. I have used Visual Studio in the past, and used the Guid.CreateGuid(). Is there a Guid class in NetBeans??

Comment: Have you tried Google ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that in NetBeans you are using java, you could use the randomUUID() method of the class java.util.UUID class as shown below

```
import java.util.UUID;

public class UUIDDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(UUID.randomUUID());
    }
}
```

For more details checkout:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html